# Why I having problem on assigning data for NMDS in R?

Tags: r, vegan, multivariate-testing

I want learn Non-matric multidimensional scale, I have these data downloaded from https://cougrstats.wordpress.com/2019/12/11/non-metric-multidimensional-scaling-nmds-in-r/
data are

```
library(vegan)
dput(orders)
structure(list(Amphipoda = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
8L, 10L, 52L, 11L, 51L, 14L, 96L, 7L, 93L, 0L, 29L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 36L, 10L, 5L, 15L, 14L, 3L, 11L, 
6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 54L, 51L, 47L, 212L, 
26L, 51L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 14L, 34L, 8L, 284L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 92L, 134L, 98L, 38L, 8L, 116L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 264L, 
104L, 114L, 138L, 152L, 42L, 46L, 10L, 67L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
12L, 0L, 26L, 0L, 67L, 456L, 7L, 2L, 46L, 155L, 82L, 124L, 596L, 
0L, 36L, 1L, 1L, 588L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 470L, 0L, 6L, 262L, 
2L, 476L, 0L, 6L, 14L, 0L, 342L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 74L, 170L, 37L, 228L, 144L, 21L, 189L, 117L, 45L, 132L, 108L, 
35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Coleoptera = c(42L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 
2L, 43L, 7L, 2L, 15L, 5L, 6L, 23L, 25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 142L, 96L, 202L, 306L, 
917L, 748L, 139L, 148L, 115L, 216L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 12L, 36L, 48L, 30L, 10L, 12L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 381L, 397L, 229L, 51L, 266L, 102L, 201L, 189L, 80L, 292L, 
271L, 583L, 641L, 318L, 729L, 520L, 582L, 262L, 59L, 209L, 134L, 
139L, 108L, 79L, 99L, 96L, 13L, 60L, 22L, 15L, 27L, 1L, 11L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 20L, 48L, 129L, 82L, 16L, 70L, 114L, 
77L, 190L, 27L, 163L, 125L, 244L, 43L, 70L, 88L, 202L, 52L, 39L, 
70L, 10L, 5L, 26L, 108L, 37L, 38L, 81L, 5L, 52L, 14L, 33L, 0L, 
26L, 12L, 41L, 3L, 5L, 15L, 1L, 10L, 18L, 31L, 40L, 22L, 23L, 
21L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 17L, 7L, 59L, 21L, 0L, 84L, 
41L, 95L, 83L, 52L, 100L, 90L, 34L, 31L, 19L, 27L, 51L, 62L, 
7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 68L, 119L, 156L, 
114L, 73L, 81L, 115L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 4L, 131L, 135L, 102L, 219L, 165L, 207L, 149L, 105L, 147L, 
195L, 332L, 316L, 22L, 55L, 17L, 12L, 50L, 49L), Diptera = c(210L, 
54L, 336L, 80L, 210L, 647L, 171L, 948L, 1495L, 751L, 877L, 912L, 
1130L, 170L, 105L, 72L, 26L, 190L, 138L, 91L, 46L, 96L, 39L, 
49L, 66L, 87L, 82L, 69L, 29L, 548L, 1240L, 810L, 999L, 521L, 
784L, 504L, 800L, 1190L, 360L, 539L, 331L, 742L, 1041L, 742L, 
154L, 787L, 479L, 411L, 1181L, 1350L, 1423L, 747L, 1827L, 1758L, 
2L, 172L, 1L, 278L, 145L, 250L, 121L, 294L, 121L, 219L, 254L, 
278L, 305L, 269L, 212L, 248L, 229L, 229L, 225L, 311L, 236L, 209L, 
257L, 226L, 655L, 440L, 416L, 39L, 398L, 323L, 461L, 670L, 934L, 
401L, 686L, 619L, 1043L, 1578L, 767L, 432L, 1754L, 1228L, 2164L, 
585L, 1336L, 933L, 928L, 454L, 833L, 928L, 745L, 604L, 69L, 1052L, 
1228L, 15L, 1835L, 1459L, 1408L, 170L, 1367L, 146L, 14L, 164L, 
101L, 780L, 779L, 259L, 537L, 576L, 480L, 1076L, 577L, 119L, 
58L, 853L, 529L, 724L, 1329L, 381L, 194L, 428L, 1240L, 1349L, 
29L, 42L, 249L, 881L, 1122L, 456L, 837L, 162L, 751L, 281L, 421L, 
36L, 803L, 553L, 562L, 1769L, 151L, 1019L, 34L, 158L, 736L, 472L, 
254L, 666L, 853L, 1175L, 795L, 1627L, 1229L, 960L, 1659L, 1719L, 
713L, 0L, 5L, 216L, 199L, 335L, 64L, 466L, 98L, 1385L, 1162L, 
1545L, 1457L, 1215L, 614L, 1247L, 1697L, 620L, 895L, 1297L, 902L, 
12L, 264L, 76L, 4L, 2L, 36L, 44L, 2L, 326L, 6L, 66L, 9L, 70L, 
13L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 42L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 70L, 4L, 120L, 
138L, 126L, 14L, 1L, 93L, 10L, 40L, 3L, 15L, 186L, 54L, 304L, 
12L, 34L, 34L, 8L, 296L, 80L, 50L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 40L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 98L, 68L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 186L, 148L, 0L, 6L, 14L, 
106L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 62L, 4L, 4L, 318L, 742L, 1099L, 298L, 553L, 
867L, 716L, 556L, 91L, 154L, 89L, 16L, 114L, 21L, 49L, 130L, 
46L, 94L, 58L, 349L, 967L, 828L, 857L, 765L, 847L, 459L, 725L, 
731L, 409L, 432L, 805L, 565L, 967L, 953L, 1398L, 999L, 1081L, 
1104L), Ephemeroptera = c(27L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 38L, 11L, 4L, 
234L, 3L, 1L, 218L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
23L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 173L, 718L, 1264L, 825L, 464L, 478L, 
456L, 816L, 481L, 811L, 652L, 146L, 686L, 563L, 372L, 190L, 419L, 
158L, 63L, 244L, 141L, 267L, 236L, 100L, 99L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 
3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 14L, 9L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 29L, 21L, 0L, 45L, 
29L, 1L, 14L, 9L, 1L, 134L, 300L, 15L, 46L, 170L, 272L, 100L, 
325L, 146L, 436L, 544L, 27L, 9L, 40L, 41L, 103L, 63L, 84L, 103L, 
629L, 133L, 584L, 74L, 25L, 191L, 489L, 212L, 304L, 118L, 78L, 
76L, 0L, 20L, 238L, 373L, 4L, 69L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 121L, 266L, 273L, 
104L, 209L, 356L, 203L, 461L, 53L, 60L, 5L, 130L, 25L, 135L, 
163L, 56L, 81L, 884L, 358L, 432L, 32L, 98L, 1L, 26L, 18L, 10L, 
11L, 1L, 68L, 3L, 9L, 0L, 32L, 5L, 41L, 106L, 85L, 240L, 27L, 
15L, 113L, 613L, 786L, 572L, 394L, 306L, 84L, 0L, 76L, 11L, 11L, 
261L, 192L, 40L, 35L, 30L, 266L, 34L, 7L, 293L, 41L, 167L, 253L, 
103L, 93L, 233L, 362L, 408L, 173L, 440L, 145L, 162L, 11L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 467L, 430L, 177L, 291L, 392L, 
231L, 82L, 361L, 29L, 0L, 31L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 3L, 17L, 8L, 15L, 
27L, 45L, 111L, 82L, 133L, 163L, 96L, 85L, 76L, 72L, 121L, 127L, 
69L, 109L, 443L, 221L, 114L, 421L, 183L, 156L), Hemiptera = c(27L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 50L, 8L, 
47L, 0L, 320L, 98L, 5L, 0L, 287L, 314L, 16L, 14L, 236L, 14L, 
2L, 627L, 279L, 6L, 254L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 12L, 36L, 6L, 14L, 104L, 
0L, 5L, 94L, 10L, 0L, 82L, 10L, 94L, 48L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 44L, 8L, 
6L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Trichoptera = c(0L, 
0L, 11L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 25L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 307L, 
332L, 224L, 92L, 210L, 213L, 239L, 195L, 75L, 372L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 
14L, 12L, 2L, 17L, 35L, 30L, 33L, 17L, 13L, 33L, 10L, 8L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 26L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 22L, 7L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 10L, 35L, 
11L, 4L, 61L, 21L, 6L, 19L, 17L, 16L, 417L, 250L, 225L, 34L, 
375L, 396L, 84L, 188L, 55L, 55L, 98L, 1145L, 713L, 342L, 2387L, 
1404L, 908L, 685L, 44L, 692L, 691L, 101L, 35L, 14L, 296L, 145L, 
44L, 274L, 62L, 31L, 49L, 1L, 135L, 24L, 219L, 2L, 60L, 6L, 0L, 
0L, 120L, 31L, 126L, 68L, 62L, 182L, 153L, 27L, 61L, 31L, 51L, 
153L, 185L, 190L, 174L, 372L, 170L, 81L, 180L, 218L, 3L, 22L, 
5L, 161L, 23L, 10L, 54L, 1L, 22L, 11L, 17L, 0L, 19L, 12L, 74L, 
13L, 29L, 64L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 193L, 561L, 97L, 112L, 241L, 19L, 
9L, 14L, 16L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 71L, 22L, 75L, 239L, 44L, 16L, 346L, 
31L, 169L, 353L, 120L, 117L, 187L, 361L, 210L, 28L, 181L, 53L, 
19L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 10L, 26L, 4L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 
4L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
107L, 230L, 52L, 14L, 46L, 44L, 29L, 85L, 7L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 7L, 90L, 97L, 166L, 243L, 160L, 62L, 
122L, 72L, 297L, 139L, 102L, 145L, 40L, 19L, 16L, 12L, 3L, 7L
), Trombidiformes = c(6L, 1L, 59L, 1L, 4L, 16L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 49L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 0L, 
15L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 31L, 31L, 59L, 48L, 111L, 155L, 153L, 116L, 
102L, 210L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 5L, 52L, 215L, 76L, 107L, 
103L, 116L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 19L, 
7L, 5L, 13L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 21L, 22L, 41L, 26L, 4L, 70L, 2L, 8L, 16L, 
0L, 48L, 35L, 6L, 3L, 16L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 8L, 43L, 17L, 9L, 
26L, 32L, 24L, 52L, 16L, 39L, 34L, 26L, 29L, 6L, 51L, 53L, 75L, 
198L, 93L, 49L, 29L, 37L, 59L, 92L, 45L, 66L, 4L, 38L, 33L, 36L, 
2L, 116L, 31L, 70L, 9L, 32L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 80L, 92L, 51L, 187L, 
75L, 130L, 143L, 128L, 83L, 80L, 67L, 76L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 47L, 14L, 
0L, 105L, 14L, 52L, 50L, 54L, 20L, 54L, 48L, 34L, 6L, 47L, 23L, 
10L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 16L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 13L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 44L, 23L, 1L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
36L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
23L, 93L, 26L, 257L, 61L, 36L, 179L, 56L, 20L, 0L, 61L, 0L, 66L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 27L, 66L, 76L, 113L, 44L, 30L, 15L, 16L, 
18L, 23L, 39L, 95L, 41L, 37L, 28L, 45L, 22L, 21L, 9L), Tubificida = c(20L, 
0L, 13L, 1L, 34L, 77L, 11L, 379L, 147L, 184L, 267L, 197L, 313L, 
2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 15L, 25L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 21L, 20L, 4L, 
30L, 3L, 17L, 11L, 15L, 0L, 2L, 8L, 139L, 133L, 292L, 158L, 94L, 
13L, 42L, 73L, 53L, 81L, 79L, 277L, 15L, 2L, 14L, 42L, 54L, 41L, 
59L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 15L, 112L, 0L, 7L, 18L, 
1L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 5L, 67L, 0L, 9L, 41L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 34L, 5L, 33L, 5L, 22L, 25L, 48L, 
0L, 3L, 16L, 9L, 0L, 152L, 10L, 1L, 13L, 4L, 0L, 25L, 1L, 65L, 
3L, 10L, 18L, 11L, 33L, 13L, 38L, 0L, 29L, 36L, 21L, 10L, 11L, 
16L, 16L, 73L, 2L, 0L, 538L, 773L, 88L, 347L, 58L, 54L, 0L, 2L, 
14L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 23L, 12L, 60L, 10L, 13L, 21L, 14L, 8L, 2L, 29L, 
4L, 5L, 23L, 11L, 21L, 41L, 196L, 128L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 
5L, 3L, 67L, 19L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 14L, 3L, 77L, 
188L, 73L, 78L, 163L, 13L, 73L, 13L, 20L, 61L, 33L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 410L, 124L, 80L, 0L, 42L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 116L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 
8L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 96L, 0L, 10L, 148L, 12L, 
17L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 
34L, 16L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 82L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
18L, 39L, 41L, 16L, 27L, 31L, 27L, 44L, 0L, 136L, 5L, 32L, 0L, 
256L, 164L, 305L, 224L, 244L, 160L, 63L, 63L, 68L, 37L, 209L, 
52L, 47L, 51L, 81L, 12L, 45L, 49L, 1L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 1L), 
    aquaticSiteType = c("stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", 
    "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "lake", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", 
    "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream", "stream")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-303L))
```

I run the NMDS code using the code below

```
set.seed(1)
metaMDS(comm = orders[,1:8],  # Define the community data 
                        distance = "bray",       # Specify a bray-curtis distance
                        try = 100)               # Number of iterations
```

It worked properly, when i assign it to another object, there is no solution

```
set.seed(1)
nmds = metaMDS(comm = orders[,1:8],  # Define the community data 
                        distance = "bray",       # Specify a bray-curtis distance
                        try = 100)               # Number of iterations 

 Best solution was not repeated -- monoMDS stopping criteria:
     2: no. of iterations >= maxit
    16: stress ratio > sratmax
     2: scale factor of the gradient < sfgrmin
```

why is this happenning? i also tried with several seeds and without seeds also, but the problem is the same.

and then when i tried the score value to data frame

```
data_scores = as.data.frame(scores(nmds))

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 303, 8
```

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: What do you mean by "worked properly?" It looks like your model didn't converge for the reasons provided. Just because it doesn't spit a warning when you don't assign the object doesn't mean it converged.

Comment: Then how to do? I am trying several times still are the same?

Comment: Yes, you are telling the optimizer to always start at the same *sets* of values even though it's trying multiple multiple starting points. This is producing the same results every time --- and every time, those results are going to be the local optimum specified above. Do not trust the results. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

`metaMDS` worked OK and gave you results. No problem.

Your problem was that you assumed that `scores` gives you a simple matrix-like object that can be converted to a `data.frame`. It does not, but it gives you a *list* of sample scores and species scores:

```r
> str(scores(nmds))
List of 2
 $ sites  : num [1:303, 1:2] -0.051 0.426 0.129 0.385 0.127 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:303] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "NMDS1" "NMDS2"
 $ species: num [1:8, 1:2] -1.178 0.351 0.269 0.339 -1.177 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "Amphipoda" "Coleoptera" "Diptera" "Ephemeroptera" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "NMDS1" "NMDS2"
```

You have two alternatives:

1. Request only one kind of scores. For instance this gives you only sample scores.

```
> str(scores(nmds, display="sites"))
 num [1:303, 1:2] -0.051 0.426 0.129 0.385 0.127 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:303] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "NMDS1" "NMDS2"
```

2. Request "tidy" scores that pack species and site scores in one data frame and add a variable that identifies the type of scores:

```
> str(scores(nmds, tidy=TRUE))
'data.frame':   311 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ NMDS1: num  -0.051 0.426 0.129 0.385 0.127 ...
 $ NMDS2: num  -0.2518 -0.1687 -0.0795 0.069 0.2453 ...
 $ score: chr  "sites" "sites" "sites" "sites" ...
 $ label: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Comment: It gave a solution, but the model didn't converge (on the global optimum). If the starting point affects the results, you're at a local optimum which is quite undesirable https://rdrr.io/cran/vegan/man/metaMDS.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. The first is the notice that "best solution was not repeated" and the second is the error trying to coerce the scores to a data.frame.

As noted in the answer by Jari Oksanen, the latter error is a consequence of trying to force an object to be a data.frame when it has dimensions that do not allow it to be coerced to a data.frame.

However, the much bigger issue is that you should not trust the scores in the first place because the model has not converged. From the [metaMDS documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/vegan/man/metaMDS.html):

> Non-linear optimization is a hard task, and the best possible solution
> (“global optimum”) may not be found from a random starting
> configuration. Most software solve this by starting from the result of
> metric scaling (cmdscale). This will probably give a good result, but
> not necessarily the “global optimum”. Vegan does the same, but metaMDS
> tries to verify or improve this first solution (“try 0”) using several
> random starts and seeing if the result can be repeated or improved and
> the improved solution repeated. If this does not succeed, you get a
> message that the result could not be repeated. However, the result
> will be at least as good as the usual standard strategy of starting
> from metric scaling or it may be improved. You may not need to do
> anything after such a message, but you can be satisfied with the
> result. If you want to be sure that you probably have a “global
> optimum” you may try the following instructions.

That different starting points (a) produce a solution but (b) the solution differs based on initial starts means the optimizer has found a local solution that can be arbitrarily far from the global solution. In other words, the results you obtain can be arbitrarily wrong and shouldn't be trusted. In other software, this would throw and not provide you the results because it wouldn't trust you not to use the known-to-be-unreliable results.

For some reason, the authors of this don't do that but you should not let their decision to make this a warning instead of an error be a reason to ignore the fundamental issues with the results.

You can follow the steps discussed in the documentation linked above to address this.